# @Binding property redraws child and parent view, when it should not

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following child view:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Queuer

struct NCMediaScrollView: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: NCMediaScrollView, rhs: NCMediaScrollView) -> Bool {
        return lhs.metadatas == rhs.metadatas
    }

    @Binding var metadatas: [tableMetadata]
    @Binding var isInSelectMode: Bool
    @Binding var selectedMetadatas: [tableMetadata]
    @Binding var columnCountStages: [Int]
    @Binding var columnCountStagesIndex: Int
    @Binding var shouldScrollToTop: Bool
    @Binding var title: String
    let proxy: ScrollViewProxy

    let queuer: Queuer

    let onCellSelected: (ScaledThumbnail, Bool) -> Void
    let onCellContextMenuItemSelected: (ScaledThumbnail, ContextMenuSelection) -> Void

    @Namespace private var topID

    var body: some View {
        let _ = Self._printChanges()

            ScrollView {
                Spacer(minLength: 70).id(topID)

                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 2) {
                    ForEach(metadatas.chunked(into: columnCountStages[columnCountStagesIndex]), id: \.self) { rowMetadatas in
                        NCMediaRow(metadatas: rowMetadatas, isInSelectMode: $isInSelectMode, queuer: queuer) { tappedThumbnail, isSelected in
                            onCellSelected(tappedThumbnail, isSelected)
                        } onCellContextMenuItemSelected: { thumbnail, selection in
                            onCellContextMenuItemSelected(thumbnail, selection)
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            // BINDING UPDATES HERE
                            title = NCUtility().getTitleFromDate(rowMetadatas.first?.date as? Date ?? Date.now)
                        }
                        .background {
                            Color.clear.preference(key: TitlePreferenceKey.self, value: title)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
            }
            .onChange(of: shouldScrollToTop) { newValue in
                if newValue {
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(topID)
                    }

                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        shouldScrollToTop = false
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

...in where in `onAppear` I update the `title` binding.

And the following parent view:

```swift
struct NCMediaNew: View {
    let downloadThumbnailQueue = Queuer(name: "downloadThumbnailQueue", maxConcurrentOperationCount: 10, qualityOfService: .background)

    @StateObject private var vm = NCMediaViewModel()
    @EnvironmentObject private var parent: NCMediaUIKitWrapper
    @State private var title = NSLocalizedString("_media_", comment: "")
    @State private var isScrolledToTop = true
    @State private var tappedMetadata = tableMetadata()

    @State private var loadingIndicatorColor = Color.gray
    @State private var titleColor = Color.primary
    @State private var toolbarItemsColor = Color.blue
    @State private var toolbarColors = [Color.clear]

    @State private var showDeleteConfirmation = false
    @State private var showPlayFromURLAlert = false
    @State private var playFromUrlString = ""

    @State private var columnCountStages = [2, 3, 4]
    @State private var columnCountStagesIndex = 0
    @State private var columnCountChanged = false

    @State private var selectedMetadatas: [tableMetadata] = []
    @State private var isInSelectMode = false

    @State private var shouldScrollToTop = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                NCMediaScrollView(metadatas: $vm.metadatas, isInSelectMode: $isInSelectMode, selectedMetadatas: $selectedMetadatas, columnCountStages: $columnCountStages, columnCountStagesIndex: $columnCountStagesIndex, shouldScrollToTop: $shouldScrollToTop, title: $title, proxy: proxy, queuer: downloadThumbnailQueue) { tappedThumbnail, isSelected in
                    if isInSelectMode, isSelected {
                        selectedMetadatas.append(tappedThumbnail.metadata)
                    } else {
                        selectedMetadatas.removeAll(where: { $0.ocId == tappedThumbnail.metadata.ocId })
                    }

                    if !isInSelectMode {
                        let selectedMetadata = tappedThumbnail.metadata
                        vm.onCellTapped(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                        NCViewer().view(viewController: parent, metadata: selectedMetadata, metadatas: vm.metadatas, imageIcon: tappedThumbnail.image)
                    }
                } onCellContextMenuItemSelected: { thumbnail, selection in
                    let selectedMetadata = thumbnail.metadata

                    switch selection {
                    case .addToFavorites:
                        vm.addToFavorites(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                    case .details:
                        NCActionCenter.shared.openShare(viewController: parent, metadata: selectedMetadata, page: .activity)
                    case .openIn:
                        vm.openIn(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                    case .saveToPhotos:
                        vm.saveToPhotos(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                    case .viewInFolder:
                        vm.viewInFolder(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                    case .modify:
                        vm.modify(metadata: selectedMetadata)
                    case .delete:
                        vm.delete(metadatas: selectedMetadata)
                    }
                }
                .equatable()
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .horizontal)
                .scrollStatusByIntrospect(isScrolledToTop: $isScrolledToTop)
            }

            HStack {
                // THIS UPDATES VIA THE BINDING
                Text(title)
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                    .foregroundStyle(titleColor)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        vm.onRefresh()
                    }

                Spacer()

                if vm.isLoadingMetadata {
                    ProgressView()
                        .tint(loadingIndicatorColor)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                }

                Button(action: {
                    isInSelectMode.toggle()
                }, label: {
                    Text(NSLocalizedString(isInSelectMode ? "_cancel_" : "_select_", comment: "")).font(.system(size: 14))
                        .foregroundStyle(toolbarItemsColor)
                })
                .padding(.horizontal, 6)
                .padding(.vertical, 3)
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial)
                .cornerRadius(.infinity)

                if isInSelectMode, !selectedMetadatas.isEmpty {
                    ToolbarCircularButton(imageSystemName: "trash.fill", color: .red)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            showDeleteConfirmation = true
                        }
                        .confirmationDialog("", isPresented: $showDeleteConfirmation) {
                            Button(NSLocalizedString("_delete_selected_media_", comment: ""), role: .destructive) {
                                vm.deleteMetadata(metadatas: selectedMetadatas)
                                cancelSelection()
                            }
                        }
                }

                Menu {
                    if isInSelectMode, !selectedMetadatas.isEmpty {
                        Section {
                            Button {
                                vm.copyOrMoveMetadataInApp(metadatas: selectedMetadatas)
                                cancelSelection()
                            } label: {
                                Label(NSLocalizedString("_move_selected_files_", comment: ""), systemImage: "arrow.up.right.square")
                            }

                            Button {
                                vm.copyMetadata(metadatas: selectedMetadatas)
                                cancelSelection()
                            } label: {
                                Label(NSLocalizedString("_copy_file_", comment: ""), systemImage: "doc.on.doc")
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        Section {
                            Picker(NSLocalizedString("_media_view_options_", comment: ""), selection: $vm.filter) {
                                Label(NSLocalizedString("_media_viewimage_show_", comment: ""), systemImage: "photo.fill").tag(Filter.onlyPhotos)

                                Label(NSLocalizedString("_media_viewvideo_show_", comment: ""), systemImage: "video.fill").tag(Filter.onlyVideos)

                                Text(NSLocalizedString("_media_show_all_", comment: "")).tag(Filter.all)
                            }.pickerStyle(.menu)

                            Button {
                                selectMediaFolder()
                            } label: {
                                Label(NSLocalizedString("_select_media_folder_", comment: ""), systemImage: "folder")
                            }
                        }

                        Section {
                            Button(action: {
                                if let tabBarController = vm.appDelegate?.window?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController {
                                    NCDocumentPickerViewController(tabBarController: tabBarController, isViewerMedia: true, allowsMultipleSelection: false, viewController: parent)
                                }
                            }, label: {
                                Label(NSLocalizedString("_play_from_files_", comment: ""), systemImage: "play.circle")
                            })

                            Button(action: {
                                showPlayFromURLAlert = true
                            }, label: {
                                Label(NSLocalizedString("_play_from_url_", comment: ""), systemImage: "link")
                            })
                        }
                    }
                } label: {
                    ToolbarCircularButton(imageSystemName: "ellipsis", color: $toolbarItemsColor)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding([.horizontal, .top], 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 20)
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: toolbarColors), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .padding(.bottom, -50)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: [.all])
            )

            if vm.hasNewMedia, !isScrolledToTop {
                Button {
                    shouldScrollToTop = true
                } label: {
                    Label(NSLocalizedString("_new_media_", comment: ""), systemImage: "arrow.up")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(10)
                .padding(.trailing, 3)
                .background(.blue)
                .clipShape(Capsule())
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .offset(.init(width: 0, height: 50))
            }
        }
        .onRotate { orientation in
            if orientation.isLandscapeHardCheck {
                columnCountStages = [4, 6, 8]
            } else {
                columnCountStages = [2, 3, 4]
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: isInSelectMode) { newValue in
            if newValue == false { selectedMetadatas.removeAll() }
        }
        .onChange(of: vm.filter) { _ in
            cancelSelection()
        }
        .onChange(of: columnCountStagesIndex) { _ in
            columnCountChanged = true
        }
        .onChange(of: isScrolledToTop) { newValue in
            withAnimation(.default) {
                titleColor = newValue ? Color.primary : .white
                loadingIndicatorColor = newValue ? Color.gray : .white
                toolbarItemsColor = newValue ? .blue : .white
                toolbarColors = newValue ? [.clear] : [Color.black.opacity(0.8), Color.black.opacity(0.4), .clear]
            }

            if newValue {
                vm.hasNewMedia = false
            }
        }
        .alert("", isPresented: $showPlayFromURLAlert) {
            TextField("https://...", text: $playFromUrlString)
                .keyboardType(.URL)
                .textContentType(.URL)

            Button(NSLocalizedString("_cancel_", comment: ""), role: .cancel) {}
            Button(NSLocalizedString("_ok_", comment: "")) {
                playVideoFromUrl()
            }
        } message: {
            Text(NSLocalizedString("_valid_video_url_", comment: ""))
        }
        .gesture(
            MagnificationGesture(minimumScaleDelta: 0)
                .onChanged { scale in
                    if !columnCountChanged {
                        let newZoom = Double(columnCountStages[columnCountStagesIndex]) * 1 / scale
                        let newZoomIndex = findClosestZoomIndex(value: newZoom)
                        columnCountStagesIndex = newZoomIndex
                    }
                }
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    columnCountChanged = false
                })
        )
    }

//..............
```

... where I show the `title` in a `Text` view.

The problem is `NCMediaScrollView` updates along with `NCMediaNew` when it shouldn't. `title` is used to display UI only in the parent, so the child should not update.

Here is an example of the view redraws every time the title updates without `Equatable`.

```
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: @self, _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: @self, _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: @self, _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: @self, _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: @self, _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: @self, _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: @self, _metadatas, _title changed.
```

An example of the same, but with Equatable in `NCMediaScrollView`:

```
NCMediaScrollView: _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: _metadatas, _title changed.
NCMediaNew: _title changed.
NCMediaScrollView: _metadatas, _title changed.
```

An example of title not updating, with Equatable in `NCMediaScrollView`:

```
NCMediaNew: _vm changed.
```

What I tried:

1. As mentioned above, I added Equtable to `NCMediaScrollView` to only diff the `metadata` array, but it still updates in this case...
2. Moved the Title view to a separate struct in hope SwiftUI would only diff this

```
struct ToolbarTitle: View {
    @Binding var title: String
    @Binding var titleColor: Color

    var body: some View {
        Text(title)
            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
            .foregroundStyle(titleColor)
            .onPreferenceChange(TitlePreferenceKey.self) { title in
                print(title)
            }
    }
}
```

I tried using a `PreferenceKey` but since this isn't a direct parent of `NCMediaScrollView` the binding doesn't work. Also tried with a regular 2-way `@Binding`, but all the views were still redrawing...

What else can work:

1. Use `introspect` to make this work via UIKit, but this is tying me up to UIKit, so it's a bad idea.
2. Use callback on `onAppear`, and update the `title` only in the parent view, so no binding will be made.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit:

Properties inside the ViewModel:

```swift
@MainActor class NCMediaViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published internal var metadatas: [tableMetadata] = []
    @Published internal var needsLoadingMoreItems = true
    @Published internal var filter = Filter.all
    @Published internal var isLoadingMetadata = true
    @Published internal var hasNewMedia = false

    internal let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    private let cache = NCImageCache.shared

    private var account: String = ""
    private var lastContentOffsetY: CGFloat = 0
    private var mediaPath = ""
    private var livePhoto: Bool = false
    private var predicateDefault: NSPredicate?
    private var predicate: NSPredicate?
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    private var timerSearchNewMedia: Timer?
    private var timeIntervalSearchNewMedia: TimeInterval = 10.0

    private var isLoadingNewMetadata = false {
        didSet {
            updateLoadingMedia()
        }
    }

    private var isLoadingOldMetadata = false {
        didSet {
            updateLoadingMedia()
        }
    }

    private var isLoadingProcessingMetadata = false {
        didSet {
            updateLoadingMedia()
        }
    }

//...........
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you have passed the `title` state property to `NCMediaScrollView` as a bound value, so as far as SwiftUI is concerned, that view needs to be updated if `title` changes.  You can't use a callback because SwiftUI views are structs, so you would likely be invoking a callback on a view that no longer exists.  I don't see why you can't use a preference key; you just need to declare it at the common ancestor.

Comment: Looks like a lot of duct tape, what is the point of Equatable in a View? That is attempting to override what SwiftUI does for redrawing. Im am sure you issue is there get rid of that and start solving your issues from there. Swiftui is very specific but if you follow its rules there is no need for duct tape.

Comment: @Paulw11 Even as a preference key the child view would still be bound and update. Can you show an example of what you mean? Thanks

Comment: @loremipsum Yes, it's very specific to the point where the smalles change outside the ordinary would need you to introspect and hack your way through problems. I will try to make it work without an Equatable, but there are so many parts to this scroll view that trying to manage the weird behaviors of SwiftUI becomes a very big problem.

Also, why would Equtable be "duct tape"? Not every diffing SwiftUI does is performant or optimized.

Comment: Your issue are likely the StateObject and EnvironmentObjects they cause complete invalidation instead of targeted redrawing. Just because the init is called or even the body it doesn’t mean that something is recreated anything in SwiftUI’s storage in meant to outlive all the recreating that comes from the nature of value types.

Comment: They do use ObservableObjects but they also talk about this when they introduced Observable this year. It is well known that the biggest drawback of these type of wrappers is the invalidation. It doesn’t work well with apps that are complex. I use DI but it is all about choices. Try changing your class to a struct and use Environment instead.

Comment: When interfacing with UIKit you do have to use reverence types but they don’t belong as EnvironmentObjects. It should be much more encapsulated.

Comment: @loremipsum (sorry, had to repost)  You can see in the `NCMediaNew` view output without `Equatable` that only _title updates and not @self or _vm or parent. I edited my original post with the view model properties. How would i be able to update the array and other business logic without an StateObject? Even Apple does that in their tutorials, they just don't call them ViewModels: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts/driving-changes-in-your-ui-with-state-and-bindings. In the case of the `parent` EnvironmentObject, this was the only way we found where we can present a UIKit VC.

Comment: I can’t see anything since you haven’t provided an MRE.